# overlaying images in a gallery

Tags: html, css, overlay

I have a gallery of images, all of which I would like to add a transparent image on top of the images.

It does in fact work for one image, but I am not sure how to position my transparent overlay image when working with more than one image. I am working with absolute positioning, which might not be optimal when working with several images in a gallery using the same class.

Take a look at my code and perhaps you can understand it better than me

```
**css**

    .related-videos{
position:relative;  
}

.related-videos img{
width: 100px; 
height: 100px;
}


.related-videos span{
width:100px;
height:100px;
display: block;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
background: url('../thumbs/overlay.png') no-repeat;
}
```

**html with one image**

```
<div class="related-videos">
<h3>Related Videos</h3>
<span></span>
<img src=".jpg" />
</div>
```

**my currently not working solution for several images**

```
<div class="related-videos">
<h3>Related Videos</h3>
<span></span>
<img src=".jpg" />
<span></span>
<img src=".jpg" />
<span></span>
<img src=".jpg" />

</div>


.related-videos{
position:relative;  
}

.related-videos img{
width: 100px; 
height: 100px;
}


 .related-videos span{
width:100px;
height:100px;
display: inline;
background: url('../thumbs/overlay.png') no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to move your `span`s *after* the `img`s in the HTML and style them like this:

```
.related-videos span {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -100px;
    background: url('../thumbs/overlay.png') no-repeat;
}
.related-videos img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[Here's a jsFiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/bTnZQ/), with random images from Wikimedia Commons for demonstration.  This solution works even if the line of images is long enough to wrap.

Answer (score 2):

Just simply delete the `top` and `left` property and change the display to `inline-block`

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gamehelp16/yg7fP/

You just need to sure that your images are in one straight row